# Unable to use user.username in base template

Tags: python, django

Hi Am trying to use the user object in my base template but user object returning null value each time even after logging into page

Please find my code here:

Views:

```
def loginView(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username =username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/rango/home/')
        else: 
            print 'No user exist'
    else:
        c= {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response('login.html', c)
```

Base template

```
<diV style="float: left;">
{% block sidebar %}
<div>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{%url 'addCategory'  %}">Add Category</a></br>
<a href="{%url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% endif %}
<a href="{%url 'register'%}">Register</a></br>
<a href="{%url 'login'%}">Login</a></br>
<a href="{%url 'about'  %}" >About</a></br>
</div>
{% endblock %}
</diV>
```

Comment: read django docs and you will find solution, this is almost trivial things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
return render_to_response('login.html', c, 
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Without the `context_instance` django will not add default context processors data in the template context. So you are not getting `user` object in the template.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `render(request, 'login.html', c)` (where render is from `django.shortcuts`.

Comment: Its not working for me i am unable to send the user information by using the HttpResponseRedirect('/rango/home/') method

Comment: I am talking about after login i am using HttpResponseRedirect by this i am unable to send the user information.

Comment: def loginView(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username =username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/rango/home/')

Comment: @user2873552, I mean the code for view that handling `'/rango/home/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` in your template.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that the [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) processor is enabled, you should just have a `user` variable available in your templates.

This processor is enabled by default, but you might have disabled it if you have overwritten `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings.

Comment: No I did not overwritten it.